# Typesafe consuming of an OData v3 provider

Tags: typescript, odata

I have an OData v3 provider, which I want to typesafely consume from a TypeScript app. Ideally, I want to generate a client from provider's metadata.

The problem is that v3 is not as much common as v2 and v4, so I haven't managed to find a way to do so.

## What I've tried:

### [odata2ts](https://github.com/odata2ts/odata2ts)

This library only supports v2 and v4 specifications. The main compatibility problem is that v3 responds with data under `response.data.value`, while v2 and v4 use different formats.

There is a [feature request for v3 support](https://github.com/odata2ts/odata2ts/issues/224). However, it seems that this won't be implemented in the nearest future.

As a workaround, a contributor of the library advises to use `application/json;odata=verbose` format when dealing with v3 providers. However, the provider I am consuming does not support such format, and always uses `response.data.value` data path.

### Converting OData spec to OpenAPI

Firstly, I converted the spec from OData to OpenAPI. For that I used [odata-openapi](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi).

Then, I used [openapi-typescript-codegen](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen) to generate a TypeScript client based on generated specification from above.

The main problem with this approach is that OData uses `Collection(id)` format to refer to an entity of this collection. In generated OpenAPI spec, for a collection there are two paths: `/Collection` and `/Collection({id})`. Generated client from this specification looks something like this:

```js
export class CollectionService {

/** ... */

// No additional parenthesis as the path is just /Collection
public static getCollection(/** ... */) {/** ... */}

// This is not valid TypeScript code. First parentheses come from parentheses inside path /Collection({id})
public static getCollection()(id: string, /** ... */) {/** ... */}

/** ... */

}
```

### Translating v3 to v2 or v4

From a quick search, I've discovered [teiid](https://teiid.io/). I suppose this can be used to as a translation layer between my OData v3 provider and odata2ts.

odata2ts could communicate with teiid, which would then translate the requests to v3 spec for the OData provider.

I think this is the most logical solution to this. However, this overcomplicates the application by a big margin. I tried to set up teiid, but quickly lost my patience. There're just too much components.

#### Update

Teiid does not support OData v3 despite claiming it does [in docs](https://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/16.0.x/content/reference/r_odata-translator.html).

> The OData translator, known by the type name "odata" exposes the OData V2 and **V3** data sources and uses the Teiid web services resource adapter for making web service calls. This translator is an extension of the Web services translator.

My setup:

- Wildfly 19.1.0
- Teiid Wildfly 16.0.0

I created a connection (I suppose it's called that) named `s1c` using following commands inside jboss-cli:

```
batch
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice/connection-definitions=s1c:add(jndi-name=java:/s1c, class-name=org.teiid.resource.adapter.ws.WSManagedConnectionFactory, enabled=true, use-java-context=true)
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice/connection-definitions=s1c/config-properties=EndPoint:add(value="http://localhost/college/odata/standard.odata")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice/connection-definitions=s1c/config-properties=SecurityType:add(value="HTTPBasic")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice/connection-definitions=s1c/config-properties=AuthUserName:add(value="admin")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice/connection-definitions=s1c/config-properties=AuthPassword:add(value="admin")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=webservice:activate
runbatch
```

And deployed a virtual database defined with xml:

```xml
<vdb name="s1c" version="1">
    <model name="s1c">
        <source connection-jndi-name="java:/s1c" name="s1c-connector" translator-name="odata"/>
    </model>
</vdb>
```

After that, I restarted the Wildfly server, and this warning pops up in terminal:

```
13:25:33,355 WARN  [org.teiid.RUNTIME] (Worker0_async-teiid-threads0)  TEIID50036 VDB s1c.1 model "s1c" metadata failed to load. Reason:Unknown ODataVersion 3.0
```

So, I suppose you cannot use Teiid for this.

## My expectations

My main goal is to have a auto-generated typesafe client for communicating with OData v3 provider. The client can use any means to achieve the goal: be it different specification or a translation layer.

The things I am not able or willing to change/sacrifice:

- The provider uses OData v3.
- Communicating with the provider must be through a typesafe wrapper which is generated from provider's metadata.

Any advice or opinion would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Did you consider Custom Wrapper Creation? Or explore other libraries?

Comment: @GuillaumeLauzier I've considered it but this seems like a task for a team of professionals. I would need to explore the underlying specifications of the protocols and changes between v3 and v2 or v4. I just want to consume the API and not to worry about the specifications. 
On the topic of other libraries, I haven't managed to find any other actively maintained libraries that would generate the client.